# Weblogic server exception BEA-000386 when trying to start the server

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

Hi I am getting this following exception when trying to start weblogic server

WebLogicServer BEA-000386 Server subsystem failed. Reason:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no orii in java.library.path
>
> ```
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no orii in java.library.path
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>   at com.oracle.jrockit.management.ThreadInfo.<clinit>(ThreadInfo.java:12)
>   at jrockit.ext.ThreadInfo$1.run(ThreadInfo.java:19)
>   at jrockit.ext.ThreadInfo$1.run(ThreadInfo.java:17)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at jrockit.ext.ThreadInfo.<clinit>(ThreadInfo.java:16)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.action.MethodMemoryAllocationStatisticsAction.getAllocatedBytesMethod(MethodMemoryAllocationStatisticsAction.java:65)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.action.MethodMemoryAllocationStatisticsAction.<clinit>(MethodMemoryAllocationStatisticsAction.java:46)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationLibrary.loadInstrumentationEngineConfiguration(InstrumentationLibrary.java:197)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationLibrary.getInstrumentationLibrary(InstrumentationLibrary.java:113)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationManager.getAvailableMonitors(InstrumentationManager.java:315)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationManager.<init>(InstrumentationManager.java:122)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationManager.getInstrumentationManager(InstrumentationManager.java:185)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.rtsupport.InstrumentationSupportImpl.getMonitor(InstrumentationSupportImpl.java:77)
>   at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationSupport.getMonitor(InstrumentationSupport.java:352)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.<clinit>(ServletRequestImpl.java)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>   at weblogic.kernel.FinalThreadLocalList.initialize(FinalThreadLocalList.java:44)
>   at weblogic.t3.srvr.PreConfigBootService.start(PreConfigBootService.java:70)
>   at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
>   at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
>   at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:802)
>   at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:489)
>   at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:446)
>   at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)
> ```

Comment: What version of weblogic? Windows or Linux? It could also be something with the jrockit install, you could try starting with a regular JDK by setting your `JAVA_VENDOR` to `Sun`

Comment: I resolved the problem, It happens because of some miss match setting in eclipse so I take eclipse preferences from a working system and import it into my eclipse after that weblogic started properly. The weblogic version is 10.3.3 and OS is windows.